# store list of objects in class

Tags: c++, list, class, object

Brand new to c++, trying to figure out how to create a class that I can store a list of objects in.

I have a surface class with subclasses such as triangles, circles, ect. 
I'm trying to create a class called Scene, that I can store a list of all the surfaces.

Here's the header file for what I'm trying to do. How do you do this in c++?

```
class Scene

{
private:
    //background color elements 
    float bgRed;
    float bgGreen;
    float bgBlue;
    //array of different surfaces
    Surface surfaces[];  //<--- What I want


public:
    Scene();
    addSurface(Surface s);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities, here's a easy one with a `std::vector`:

```
vector<Surface> surfaces;
...
addSurface(const Surface &s) //const and & are not strictly necessary, but better
{
    surfaces.push_back(s);
}  
...
//accessing like an array: surfaces[index]
//element count: surfaces.size()
```

This copies the passed objects (`s`) while inserting. If you want the same object, so that changes in the vector affect the object "outside" too (and vice-versa), you'll need an additional pointer.
Also note that copying of an child class object of Surface will result in a pure Surface, without the child class part (object slicing). If you need that part, you'll need a pointer too (if you don't have one already).

```
//pointer variant
vector<Surface*> surfaces;
...
addSurface(Surface &s)
{
    surfaces.push_back(&s);
}
```